How to install Ros2 Jazzy on Debian from source
Please how do I install ros2 Jazzy from source, also can I install it in a particular directory other than the home, like in a sub directory? and lastly is there a containarized version of ROS2 so I don't have to install it locally at all.

Welcome at RSE. The next time, please open a separate question for every question you have.

You can have a look into the docker files in this repo about how to install ROS 2 on debian 12.
There are plenty of docker images available. The official ones and others from the community like this ones. See this REP for which packages are included in which variant.

Thanks man, for your response.

You can follow this tutorial for installing ros2 jazzy from source on your system. I haven't installed ros2 from source yet, so I can't be sure can you install it to a subdirectory. But I think there should not be any problem because you will source the directory where you install ros2.
And for your last question, you can find the docker image from this docker
Hub link.

Thanks Guys but I Just dual booted Ubuntu 24.04 Noble, and save my self the hasle .
I also tried to install it (ros2 Jazzy) in ubuntu from Binary as I am interested in contributing , but it kept failing, so I installed the deb package form instead with Gazebo harmonic, so can I still make contribution with the deb package installation method?

Build and install from source just happens in a Colcon workspace like any other workspace. So you can put it wherever you want.

I just did it on a Raspberry Pi and put it in the hidden ~/.local directory: https://github.com/danzimmerman/dz_rpi_config/wiki/installing_ros2#ros-2-jazzy-source-install
